# IAM Roles and EC2 access to user identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I was checking out videos on accessing aws using ssh.

He just added a IAM role while creating EC2 instance. When I ssh to EC2 instance from cli I was easily able to run "aws s3 ls". My question is how does it will know whether I belong to that IAM role or not?

While starting ssh connection I gave only the public IP of EC2 and keypair related to that EC2 instance.

> **So where exactly I allowed my identity to be shared with aws?**

When I didnot added the role while creating ec2 instance I have to explicitly give my keys for accessing aws services.

> So what IAM role do on the fly that it donot ask for credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First don't interrelate PEM(keypair) and IAM. Both are not connected each other.

> What is IAM?
>
> AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) enables you to manage access
>   to AWS services and resources securely.

From the explanation itself it's clear that that, it enables access to AWS resources. So lets take one simple example, you want to access S3 Bucket from the AWS EC2 Instance you created. For that you need to provide `Accesskey` and `Secretkey`, From where you will get the access key and secret key, which can be generated by creating a User/Role using IAM. Both have the Creds generated. Now lets see abot Role. Role can be assumed by a USER/Resource(EC2), now if you assign a Role to a EC2 then the Instance by default will get all the permissions associated with that role, means it gets the Accesskey and SeceretKey. Now if you ran some `aws s3 ls` command then it will retrieve the keys from the default path and access the AWS Resource(here S3).

> What is EC2 Keypair(PEM)?
>
> > Amazon EC2 uses public–key cryptography to encrypt and decrypt login
> >     information. Public–key cryptography uses a public key to encrypt a
> >     piece of data, such as a password, then the recipient uses the private
> >     key to decrypt the data. The public and private keys are known as a
> >     key pair.

The Keypair is only associated with your EC2 instance and it can't be used to access any other AWS resources. It has no dependency with IAM. You are not sharing any identity with AWS. The private key is owned by you(PEM file) and the public key is kept inside the EC2 instance in this file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` . If you want to change your keys and delete the Amazon provided keypair, just delete the default one and place the new public key in the above file. Now you can use the new keypair to login to your instance.

Thus your keypair and IAM are not interconnected anywhere. For more details

[AWS EC2 Keypair](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html)

[AWS IAM Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction.html)

Comment: I agree with the workflow you stated that IAM Role provide all the user access key to ec2 instance for accessing services and EC2 KeyPair is only for ec2 access using ssh. But don't you think this is kind of security issue too that when someone gets access to ec2 key pair then that person will have free access to all the services or may be I don't know whether cli has that much control or not

Comment: @Ladoo you keep saying that someone is going to get access to the key pair. The key pair is the same as a password. It is your security credentials. Why would someone be able to gain access to your SSH key pair?

Comment: @MarkB then I was bit confused about the process. Now I have got myself clear about the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The IAM role is assigned to the entire EC2 instance. Any code running on that EC2 instance gets the IAM role. The IAM role is completely unrelated to the SSH account you use to login to the EC2 instance.

Comment: I agree with what you say. but when I ssh I donot provide my credentials to verify. I may be anyone who luckily got access to keypair and public ip of that particular ec2

Comment: how does above is taken care of?

Comment: The key pair is the credentials... You should be keeping your secret SSH key file as secure as a password.